# How to run two separate ARKit experiences in one iOS app

Tags: swift, scenekit, augmented-reality, arkit, realitykit

I have a problem with running two `ARKit` experiences in one app. I have main menu View Controller which runs either of the experiences. It looks something like that:

- `MainVC` - main `UIViewController` with two buttons to choose the experience
- `ARVC1` - first experience `UIViewController`
- `ARVC2` - second experience `UIViewController`

Both experiences are independent and they don't need to pass any data between each other.
Unfortunately when I dismiss `ARVC1` or `ARVC2` and run the second one, somehow I have traces of the previous `ARSession` (still frame from previous session is flashing once for a while). Can I reset completely `ARSession` somehow? It seems that it stays somewhere in the background. I've tried to pause the session when I dismiss any of the View Controllers but it didn't help.

The same happens if I open `ARVC1` and press the button to show statistics:

```
arView.debugOptions = [.showStatistics]
```

After dismissing `ARVC1` and opening it again it still shows statistics so it's running somewhere in the background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem:

After opening and closing `ARVC1` and quickly opening `ARVC2` I was experiencing flickering of the previous `ARSession` in current `ARSession`. To solve this I create `ARView` in my `MainVC` and I pass the reference to it to destination controller, where I set up the `arView` constraints programmatically. To avoid passing the `ARAnchors` I reset configuration with options in `viewDidLoad`:

```
arView.session.run(configuration, options: [.resetTracking,.removeExistingAnchors,.stopTrackedRaycasts])
```

It helped as well with `UINavigationController` transition (made it smoother) because `ARSession` is configured before the View is presented and it eliminates the black flash that occurs at the moment when you run new `ARConfiguration` with `ARSession`.

It also eliminates the console error (below) that I was experiencing while quickly closing and opening `ViewController` containing `ARView` which sometimes was crashing the app:

> [Session] Session (0x160879b40): did fail with error: Error
>   Domain=com.apple.arkit.error Code=102 "Required sensor failed."
>   UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=A sensor failed to deliver the
>   required input., NSUnderlyingError=0x283f959b0 {Error
>   Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11800 "The operation could not be
>   completed" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=An unknown error
>   occurred (-12780), NSLocalizedDescription=The operation could not be
>   completed, NSUnderlyingError=0x283efc8a0 {Error
>   Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-12780 "(null)"}}},
>   NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Make sure that the application has the
>   required privacy settings., NSLocalizedDescription=Required sensor
>   failed.} 2020-01-09 16:20:38.600835+0000 App[573:231750]
>   [Technique] World tracking performance is being affected by resource
>   constraints [3] 2020-01-09 16:20:38.600977+0000
>   App[573:231750] [Technique] VIO error callback: 8506.590769,
>   3, Frame time stamps are either out of order or repeating

Comment: After deeper investigation I find out that my issue with flickering of the ARViews was caused by memory leak (one of delegates wasn't "weak"). Because of that I had more than one ARSession running at one time. After removing the leak I get back to creating ARViews in separate View Controllers so it don't have to run in the background in the MainVC.